# Does rsync completely overwrite files with different timestamps?

Tags: linux, networking, osx, rsync, synchronization

I've used a command similar to this to `rsync` files from macOS to Linux:

```
rsync -avz <ip-address>:/Backup/ Backup/
```

The folder `Backup/` was previously copied from the same machine using `scp`, with no files changed. I thought that `rsync` would be a noop, but it started to overwrite all files (probably, because of different timestamps), causing a lot of disk writes. I've tried the same command with `--size-only` and it finished almost instantly. Does `rsync` *completely overwrite* the files that have different timestamps (i.e. not checking the difference)? Does it depend on the size of the files?

Comment: Use `-i` instead of `-v` to see _why_ a file transfers. Read the manual about `--itemize-changes`.

Comment: @Kusalananda So if I see something like `>f..t...... /path/to/file` when using `-i`, does it mean that the file is completely overwritten? Why does `rsync` do it if only  modification time differs?

Comment: Then it applies its delta algorithm to transfer the bits of the file that has changed.  If no data in the file has changed, `rsync` still has to send the checksums for each block in the file across to verify that this is in fact the case. The block size is determined from the size of the file as mentioned in the documentation for `-B`.  Also try running with `--stats` to get final stats for the transfer. Calculating the checksums for the delta algorithm involves _reading_ the complete file.

Answer (score -1):

read the fine manual of rsync:

```
       It is famous  for  its
       delta-transfer  algorithm,  which  reduces the amount of data sent over
       the network by sending only the differences between  the  source  files
       and  the  existing  files in the destination.
```

I think you're getting read i/o, not write. Are you sure in rsync overwrite the files and not only scanning the content of them?

Comment: I don't think this quote illustrates what you want it to, since regardless of what goes over the network traffic it could still rewrite the files locally (which it has to do when there *are* changes).

Comment: Yes, I'm sure (I checked with `iotop`). I know about the delta-transfer algoritm, the question was why it didn't work.

Comment: Because the files are really different? Check them with `md5sum`.

Comment: No, that's not the case either.

Comment: Then fill a bugreport.